# Why does TextBox Leave fire when mouse leaves?

Tags: winforms

I thought that Leave was supposed to fire when a control loses focus, and MouseLeave was supposed to fire when the mouse is no longer in the control.

I have a TextBox, and if I click in it, then take the mouse out, the Leave event fires. I'm using Leave to validate the entry in the box, like when people hit tab to go to the next control.

Does this mean that a TextBox can't have focus unless the mouse remains in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have some other code setting focus, because Leave does not fire when the mouse moves out of the control.

Comment: I will go check that... Yup, there's another control taking focus on MouseEnter, which causes the TextBox to Leave. Thanks! Will accept after the 5 minutes is up.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `Leave` or `LostFocus` for validation purposes, instead use [`TextBox.Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) which is designed specifically for validation scenarios.

This way, if you want to have a `Cancel` button for example, you can just set its `CausesValidation` property to false and editor controls `Validating` events will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the mouse is in it. Property Focus refers to another type of event, when a component is ready to have its value changed, It doesn't matter if you use the keyboard or the mouse. Why don't you validate TextBox value when the Textbox looses Focus?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I thought the "Leave" event was supposed to fire when the TextBox loses focus. What's happening is that the Leave event also fires when the mouse leaves the control.

Comment: Yes! That's what I tried to explain, sorry! Type tour validation code in the Focus event (lost focus event)